# Amazon S3 - URL of uploaded image downloads image instead of displaying in browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am successfully uploading an image to my Amazon S3 bucket, but when I go to the URL that it is generated, my image is instantly downloaded instead of being displayed in the browser.  My code is below:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

 AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
 AWS.config.accessKeyId = "MY_ACCESS_KEY";
 AWS.config.secretAccessKey = "MY_SECRET_KEY";
 AWS.config.region = "us-west-2";
 AWS.config.apiVersions = {
    "s3": "2006-03-01"
 }

 var s3 = new AWS.S3();

 var bodystream = fs.createReadStream('./meme1.png');

 var params = {
    'Bucket': 'MY_BUCKET_NAME',
    'Key': 'uploads/images/' + 'Img4.png',
    'Body': bodystream,
    'ContentEncoding': 'base64', 
    'ContentType ': 'image/png',
    'ACL':'public-read-write'
 };

 s3.upload(params, function(err, data){
    console.log('RESPONSE: ', err, data);
 });
```

Some other posts say to make sure the `ContentType` property of the `params` object is correct but I am pretty sure that mine is correct.  How do I fix this and make the image display in the browser instead of downloading?

Comment: "I am pretty sure that mine is correct." -- did you check it using F12 in a browser or another method, or is this just a guess?

Comment: @DaveS how do you use F12?  I say that I think it is correct cuz it is a `.png` image and I set the `ContentType` to `image/png`

Comment: If you put the link into a page, and have the F12 window open in your browser you can record all network traffic and look at the headers that AWS sent you when the image was fetched.

Comment: I don't *think* `Content-Encoding: base64` works this way. That's an email thing, not a web thing.  The file you're downloading is probably not actually usable as an image.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the Content Disposition, by default it's "attachement" which means the file is being downloaded instead of displayed.

```
ContentDisposition: inline
```

(Answering this Question for Googlers)